# No such module 'Podname' installed from a developing pod and building from main project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have this problem but it is different with my previous researchs. This is my context:

I have created my own pod name "myPod" and it is set as Swift 5 language. This pod needs 'Alamofire' pod and when I install 'Alamofire 5' into 'MyPod' it is cleaned and compiled without problems. So, when I trying to clean and compile my 'MyPod' into the main project with Objective.-C language it gives an error that it says:

No such module 'Alamofire'.

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1, Objective-C in my main project, Swift 5 in my Pod, Alamofire ~> 5.0.0-rc.2, my Podspec it settled down in Swift 5 Language.

I have already tried:

- Set my Swift version in 5 into 'MyPod' and my main project.
- Set "platform :ios, '10.0'" in Podfiles (MyPod and main project)
- Migrate old code and migrate Swift 4 to Swift 5

Please, someone has any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should add dependency in your .podspec file

```
spec.dependency 'Alamofire'
```